# Good way to use/design dbt relation test

Tags: dbt

I would like to have a dbt relation test for a model m_0.

```
models:
  - name: m_0
    columns:
      - name: customer_id
        tests:
          - relationships:
              to: ref('m_1')
              field: id
```

Then I got two questions:

1. I'm running the model m_0 under schema s_a, how to handle the case that m_1 does not exist? There's no guarantee of m_1 must be run before m_0.
2. How to guarantee the relation test result is not flaky? Since m_0 and m_1 are scheduled independently, some latest id may not read from m_1 but are already in m_0.

Any good practice for writing a dbt relation test? Is there any requirements of m_0 and m_1? Such as m_1 should be a parent table of m_0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The test is its own node, which will be downstream in the DAG from both m_0 and m_1. If you run a command like `dbt build`, dbt will first build m_0 and m_1 before running this relationship test. However, you are right that if you run `dbt test -s m_0` and m_1 is not yet built, the test will fail. If you want to avoid this failure, you can use `dbt test -s m_0 --indirect-selection=cautious` and the relationship test will not run. See [the docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/test-selection-examples#indirect-selection)
2. You should consider adding a `where:` config to this test, that limits the records tested in `m_0`. For example, `where: created_at < current_timestamp - interval '1 day'`. This should leave "extra" records in m_1, but this test is only concerned about missing records in m_1, so it will pass